# Select several items

Tags: pantheon-files, file-management

Sorry maybe I am stupid but I don´t know how to select several files in File Manager or several mails in Pantheon Mail

Answer (score 0):

In Files, there are several ways to do this.  Assuming you are using the default grid view you can:

With the mouse

- Select each item by clicking on the tick emblem that appears when you hover over it or
- Hold down the `<Ctrl>` key and click anywhere on each item you want to select or
- Hold down the `<Shift>` key and click anywhere on the first and last item you want to select.  All items in a linear sequence between these two items will also be selected or
- Press and hold down the primary button over whitespace and drag the pointer to create a selection rectangle (rubberband). Any item this includes will be selected.

With the keyboard alone you can

- With the arrow keys. move the cursor to the first item to select. Hold down the `<Shift>` key and move the cursor to the last item to select - all items in between in a linear sequence will be selected or
- Move the cursor to the first item to selected. Hold down the `<Ctrl>` and `<Alt>` keys. Move the cursor to the next item to select. Press `+` or `=` to select that item.  You can also deselect items in the same way by pressing the `-` key. Or
- You can select all items with the shortcut `<Ctrl>A` or
- You can invert any existing selection with the shortcut `<Ctrl><Shift>A`

These methods work pretty much the same in the other views except for rubberbanding you click on the filename or any other column (not the icon) to commence.

I do not know about Mail - I do not use it but some of these methods might work.